# CSSTransition: Error: Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components) or a

Tags: css, reactjs, reactcsstransitiongroup

I am trying to implement a simple CSS transition using React's `CSSTransition`. I simply want to animate a thin line going straight across the screen.
Here is the following code.
Grid.js

```
class Gridline extends React.Component {
    render() {
        return(
            <CSSTransition
            in = {true}
            appear = {true}
            classNames = "line-col"
            timeout={200}>
                    <div className = 'line'></div> 
            </CSSTransition>   
        );
    }
}
```

And here is the relevant CSS

```
.line-col-appear{
    height: 0%;
    width: 2px;
}
.line-col-appear-active{
    height: 100%;
    width: 2px;
    transition: height 200s linear;
}
.line-col-appear-done{
    height: 100%;
    width: 2px;

}
.line-col-enter{
    height: 0%;
    width: 2px;
}
.line-col-enter-active{
    height: 100%;
    width: 2px;
    transition: height 2s linear;
}
.line-col-enter-done{
    height: 100%;
    width: 2px;

}
```

Any help on resolving this error would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

RESOLVED. I had to kill the port and restart the app.